How to set grafana to show only dashboards?
I have grafana embedded inside my react app but i want it to show ONLY the dashboards section so the operator can only navigate between dashboards. I dont want to show Home, Connections or any oter options.
I tried adding kiosk to the URL but i only managed to make it work to a single dashboard.
